# Do different browsers handle various PHP functions differently?

Tags: php, browser, compatibility

**Context:** I'm currently working on a MATLAB script that decodes messages encrypted with a 1:1 letter-replacement scheme.  It works by finding the the most common character in the message and remapping it to the letter of corresponding commonness based on stats found online.  To help with the demo, I'm writing a message with letter frequencies that correspond exactly with the ones in the script.  To help write this letter, I developed a rudimentary HTML form with accompanying PHP script (live at http://nd.edu/~wbadart/letter) which count the letters in the input, rank them, and display the rank along side the desired rank.

**Question:** I'm using Firefox, and the tool worked just fine, but it was displaying incorrect values for my teammates in Chrome and Safari.  One of the most telling errors was that Chrome and Safari both incorrectly displayed a variable `$mssgLen` which was nothing more than the `strlen()` of the input.  Does anyone know what could account for these discrepancies?

Thanks!

Comment: PHP is server-side. Thus the browser has nothing to do with how it works or not. You should check deeper into you PHP code and check what it could depent on.

Comment: Is the content of `$mssgLen` static or coming from the browser? Try outputting the value of that and load it in all three browsers, what do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add encoding to the head section of html and try to use mb_strlen instead of strlen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

PHP is server side language, so there is no difference between browsers.

Difference might be what are default values for encoding the request and how it is handled. Thats where the strlen difference might occur.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the browsers terminate lines differently. E.g. "\n\r" instead of just "\n" or vice-versa. var_dump or debug your input so you can see those minor differences.